# Mag stripe keyboard wedge print speed

Tags: input, hardware, keyboard-wedge

I am writing an application where I need to accept information from a mag swipe keyboard edge. I am running into concerns in regards to the wedge's print speed. Any lag in the application, even at input, is very important.

I can not seem to find an answer to this question:

What is the main bottleneck for a mag stripe reader's print speed (keyboard wedge specific via usb or usb slave)?

I have noticed that the print speed differs from machine to machine. I want to say that it is either the usb port or the RAM on the device but I unfortunately don't know enough about the hardware end of things to come to a conclusion. Furthermore might it be the operating system or card reader? I know the reader itself has a print speed but that does not explain the fluctuation.

Anyone know as to what it might be?

Comment: what is considered a lag? 1 sec from end of swipe or more?

Comment: @StevenMartin it ranges from ~200 milliseconds to  ~1500 milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it is the baud rate. You can change the baud rate on the computer and the card reader to adjust the speed at which the data (or print) speed is sent/received.